# webservice provider to relational db using informatica powercenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have requirement to load the data from web-service into the target database using Informatica. The web-service will be initiated by the source application whenever there is a change in source side. From Informatica side, we have to trigger the loading job whenever we receive the web-service instead of scheduling/batch jobs. using informatica powercenter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see a general requirement but the specific question is not clear to me. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using informatica 10.2 hotfix1. i have imported .wsdl and created simple mapping in that one is webservice target and other one is relational DB. When i debug i see values are passing till target but it did not get inserted in the DB. Also client is already pumping messages using endpoint url provided to them. I have scheduled my job to run continuously when setting up session properties "idle time=-1" and "message count=-1"  did not work. Please let me know this is understable.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding the issue. Please post some more deatails or logs. Where can you see the values, what are the target settings?